# Add a class to a div under a certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to add a class to a div when a certain condition is true. My code is as follows:

```
$('.addressStatus').each(function(index, value){
    var el = 0;
    if($(this).data('status') == true){
         el =  $(this).data('param1');
         console.log(el);
         var id = document.getElementById('statusID'+el);
         id.classList.add('inactiveAddrsColor');                
    }
});
```

Comment: please share your html code also

Comment: why so many down votes? I dont see whats the problem here with the question. He has syntax issues thats it.. why the need of HTML?

Comment: @Reddy Guessing here, but some things the post could be improved with: more readable formatting (the preview is live when editing), removing or explaining the commented-out code, adding enough code for a [mcve], spellcheck, bit more context, further explain "tried jquery also" (would OP prefer not to use jQuery? why does the sample code mix jQuery and vanilla dom js like that?), further research, explanation of what "didn't worked" exactly means (error? no effect? etc).

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues, Use this code

```
$('.addressStatus').each(function(index, value){
        var el = 0;
        if($(this).data('status') == true){
             el =  $(this).data('param1');
             console.log(el);
             $('#statusID'+el).addClass('inactiveAddrsColor'); // note the #                                                  
        }
});
```

you had almost got it right with this one `$('statusID'+el).addClass('inactiveAddrsColor');` but it should have been this `$('#statusID'+el)`;

---

**EDit 1:** after you mentioned that the HTML you have is

```
 <div data-status = "#{addr.inactiveStatus}" class="addressStatus" data-param1 = "#{addr.id}" id="addsStatusID">
   <div id="statusID#{addr.id}" ><div>........</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

if `addr.id` == `test` then your div id would be `statusID#test`. Meanwhile your 
`data-param1` of the parent div will be `#test`.

So doing `'#statusID'+el` will be equal to `#statusID#test`, then we do this `$('#statusID#test')` which means a element with 2 id's which is totally wrong. try replacing your `#` with some other special character (may be `_`). And it must work fine.

Comment: The id of the div is dynamic <div data-status = "#{addr.inactiveStatus}" class="addressStatus" data-param1 = "#{addr.id}" id="addsStatusID"> <div id="statusID#{addr.id}" ><div>........</div></div></div> . Can this be a problem? The code will repeat again

Comment: oh!!  your div id is this ? `<div id="statusID#{addr.id}" >` Let em update my answer.

Comment: Actually am working on JSF and Primefaces in that suppose if id = 10,#{addr.id} will give value as 10 and not #10. And if i wont use # it will return {addr.id} itself as a string.

Comment: in that case `$('#statusID'+el).addClass('inactiveAddrsColor');` must work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like so:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.addressStatus').each(function(index, value) {
    if ($(this).data('status') == true) {
      var id = '#statusID' + $(this).data('param1');
      $(id).addClass('inactiveAddrsColor');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.inactiveAddrsColor { color: #bbb; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="addressStatus" data-param1="a" data-status="false">First</div>
<div class="addressStatus" data-param1="b" data-status="true">Second</div>
<div class="addressStatus" data-param1="c" data-status="false">Third</div>
<div class="addressStatus" data-param1="d" data-status="true">Fourth</div>
<hr>
<span id="statusIDa">A/first</span> |
<span id="statusIDb">B/first</span> |
<span id="statusIDc">C/first</span> |
<span id="statusIDd">D/first</span>
```

Comment: <div data-status = "#{addr.inactiveStatus}"  class="addressStatus" data-param1 = "#{addr.id}" id="addsStatusID">
               <div id="statusID#{addr.id}"  ><div>........</div></div></div>     I typed enter by mistake. The id getting is dynamic it changes each time. will it affect this.?